# passing a generator to field_values in django-autofixture

Tags: python, django, generator

Referring to [django-autofixture documentation](http://packages.python.org/django-autofixture/usage.html#autofixture), I wrote the following code (edited for terseness):

```
    def random_state_generator(self, states=None): 
        import random
        if not states: 
            states = "waiting|email|post|einv".split('|')
        while 1: 
            yield random.choice(states)
```

...

```
   rsg = self.random_state_generator()
   self.create_test_foo(10, values={'state': rsg})
```

...

```
    field_values = dict(field_values.items() + values.items())
    foo_fixture = AutoFixture(FooClass, overwrite_defaults=True, 
                              generate_fk=generate_fk_values,
                              field_values=field_values)
    bunch_of_stuff = foo_fixture.create(foo_count)
```

Okay, 
now when I have the DB all set up, and I filter myself a list of stuff, 
and go

```
for foo in bunch_of_stuff: print (foo.state)
```

instead of getting the expected random state string, I get the following output:

> generator object random_state_generator at 0x242c640>

which is not what I'd expect based on the documentation, specifically

> field_values: A dictionary with field names of model as keys. Values may be static values that are assigned to the field, a Generator instance that generates a value on the fly or a callable which takes no arguments and returns the wanted value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the field_values takes a class instance from autofixture.generators, so all I had to do was: 
generate the list of states;

```
from autofixture.generators import ChoicesGenerator
states = "waiting|email|post|einv".split('|')
rsg = ChoicesGenerator(values=states)
self.create_test_foo(10, values={'state': rsg})
```

the misunderstanding rose from confusing autofixture's generators with generic python generators.

Answer (score 0):

In case when u just want some raw data you can use :
`def create_doctor():
    if Doctor.objects.all().count() == 0:
        import random
        avail_item = ['Hart', 'Kidney', 'Lungs', 'Ear', 'Bones']
        for i in range(10):
            fixture = AutoFixture(Doctor,
                                  field_values={'user_name': 'GauravTyagi',    'speciality': random.choice(avail_item)})
            fixture.create(1)
    else:
        print 'Doctors exist in table .........))))))))))))'`